# how to get the currently tapped image's url and name inside of listbox datatemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

below is the wp app code in xaml. code loads number of  images and its name. Now i want to get the currently tapped image's url and name to be passed as parameters into another page to load that particular imgae and name. help me.

```
<ListBox Name="tileList" Grid.Row="2" Margin="12,0,14,0" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TileName}"></TextBlock>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImgUri}" Height="200" Width="350" Margin="5,0,0,0" Tap="on_Tap">
                </Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really basic thing that you should figure out by yourself. But I give theory here not code.

- Look for ListBox selection changed event. and then from this
     typecast the sender as ListBox and from this get the SelctedItem.
     This selected Item will be type of ItemClass of your List is made of
     say - List that you have set as Itemsource of Listbox.
- As till now you got the Selected ItemClass object that will
     contain TileName and ImageUri. So use the MVVM Messenger Class to
     send this item to next page. You can google it how use MVVM
     messenger you wil find the Answer.

I can give you the code but I think in starting phase you should try lots of thing by yourself. happy learning :)

Edit 1:-

Hi The way You send the parameter from one page to another is correct. Here is the screenshot.
[image]

[**Source Page-navigation with parameters**](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-windows-phone-alternatives)

Can you tell me what is not working ? are you getting any exception ?

Any question just comment.

Comment: i tried of visual tree helper but not working. now im trying your instructions. it gives me result. thanks.

Comment: can i use the follwing code instead MVVM Messenger? CODE:NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Options.xaml?name="+msg+"&url="+url, UriKind.Relative));

Comment: @BalaManikandan You can use my name that would me much better :). It should work i think. Let me check it come back to you. but this should work.

Answer (score 1):

@loop im getting tilename and imguri in variable name by using the following code

```
ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;
   var name = lb.SelectedItem;
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Options.xaml?name=" + name, UriKind.Relative));
```

help me to get the  tilename and imguri values from variable name.

Comment: just typecast to correspoind itemclass of list<itemclass> like -- (ItemClass)(lb.SelectedItem) and then.. get value like this :-  name.ImgUri and name.TileName.